# Unit testing a Bottle app

Tags: python, unit-testing, bottle

What is the best the best way to develop unit tests for a Bottle based WSGI app?
I've been trying to use WebTest but have been failing miserably.

Comment: Be more specific. What have you tried, where did you fail. How does your setup look like, show some code, configuration, etc.